# why Jetty can't support duplicate charset in Content Type header?

Tags: http, http-headers, jetty

Recently I found a phenomenon of jetty. In eclipse I installed a jetty plugin to run web project. In page(jsp) there is a ajax request, I found if project is started by jetty there is 500 error, but if started by tomcat, it's ok. See below:

```
curl -d "category=foo" 'http://localhost:8080/foo/bar' -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 22 Dec 2015 13:27:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 20086
Server: Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031)
curl: (18) transfer closed with 20086 bytes remaining to read
```

please warning content type header above, charset is duplicate, so cause this error. 
Then I changed code of setting content type, request again, it's ok now.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 24 Dec 2015 03:00:33 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 83
Server: Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031)
{"altMessage":null,"desc":null,"map":null,"message":"[]","prop":null,"rsCode":"ok"}
```

So I'd like to know why Jetty can't support duplicate charset in Content Type header?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test in jetty-9.3 and the following test passes fine:

```java
@Test
public void testStrangeContentType() throws Exception
{
    Response response = newResponse();

    assertEquals(null, response.getContentType());

    response.recycle();
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8;charset=UTF-8");
    response.getWriter();
    assertEquals("text/html;charset=utf-8;charset=UTF-8",response.getContentType());
    assertEquals("utf-8",response.getCharacterEncoding().toLowerCase());
}
```

So this looks like it is fixed in the latest jetty releases.  Jetty-8 has been [end of life for some time](https://webtide.com/jetty-7-and-jetty-8-end-of-life/) so can you upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug.

It's been filed at the RT/Jetty issue tracker under https://bugs.eclipse.org/485376